# linux sed replace white space with new line not working as expected

Tags: sed, newline

below command working properly in UNIX but it is not replacing the new line in LINUX.

```
#! /bin/sed -f
:loop
/[^]$/N
s/\n//
t loop
```

I have tried multiple option but nothing seems to be working. any suggestions?

Comment: What is `[^]` supposed to match?

Comment: this is the character i have at the end on the line. so basically i don't want to append next line to current if this character found.

Comment: Just to confirm again you prefer NOT  to append the next line to a line that end with "^"? Reason why I ask is that I noticed your Question title has something to do with "white space with new line"

Answer (score 1):

`[^]` is an invalid expression. I don't know why your version of sed accepts it, but in POSIX sed `^` at the beginning of a list inverts it. That is to say, `[^abc]` matches all characters except `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Furthermore, to match a `]` in a list, it has to appear right after the opening `[` or the inverting `^`. `[]abc]` matches  `a`, `b`, `c`, and `]`, whereas `[^]abc]` matches any character except those four. Because of this, sed cannot find a closing `]` to the list `[^]` and fails with an error.

To match a literal `^`, use `\^`:

```
#! /bin/sed -f
:loop
/\^$/N
s/\n//
t loop
```